# Dynamic resize a div while scrolling using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am searching for a jQuery-solution for my fixed header. If the user scrolls down, the header shall shrink in the same way the scrolling position is until a minimum height is reached.

**Example:**
scrolling position: `0`
div height: `250px`

scrolling position: `85`
div height: `165px (=250px-85)`

scrolling position: `435`
div height: `100px (=minimum height)`

Here is the quick [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f127rwww/).

```
body {
    height: 1000px;
}

.header {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: lightblue;
    height: 250px;
    width: 100%;
}

<div class="header"></div>
```

---

Here is the solution for me: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vq9vo74L/2/)

Comment: You should at least have basic knowledge of js and jQuery, if you want to have help for question related to that. SO is not there to write your code, but to help you  problems you have with your implementation.

Comment: I do have basic knowledge at least so far as that I can understand the code and do minor changes. For more, there is a big lack of understanding up to now. Sorry for not being able to change this up to now. :-(

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of the [Window Scroll Event](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) and `scrollTop()` function to achieve the same.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var distanceFromTop = $(document).scrollTop();
    if(distanceFromTop < 84 )
    {
        // set div height to 250px
    }   
    else if(distanceFromTop == 85)
    {
        // reduce the div height
    }
    else if(distanceFromTop > 85 && distanceFromTop <= 434)
    {
        // do something with height if required
    }
    else if(distanceFromTop > 434)
    {
        // set div height to 100px
    }   
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/vq9vo74L/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: Yes, this is the right way. The only thing i imagined was a smoothly fading header, so the js should calculate the exact amount of scrolled pixels from top and take them away (and add them back of course when scrolling up again).

Comment: You can also add transition:all .4s ease; in CSS for a nicer animation.